# custom spacing between linearlayout views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a list of linearlayouts with textview, imageviews and button inside of them. here is an example of one linearlayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/strength_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/attribute"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/strength_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/strength_dice_1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dice_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/strength_dice_2"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dice_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/strength_roll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/roll"
    android:onClick="strength_roll_onclick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I get the following layout with this:

[image: linearlayout]

now, I want the imageviews and the button to be align to the right, while the textview stays in the left side, but I don't know how to make it happen.

Comment: use table row in apply weight ...attribute

Comment: you can use weight sum and layout weight to align it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<TableRow android:height="wrap_content"
          android:width="match_parent"
          android:weight_sum="1" >
   <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/strength_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    *android:weight=".4"*
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/strength_dice_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:weight=".2"**
    android:src="@drawable/dice_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/strength_dice_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:weight=".2"**
    android:src="@drawable/dice_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/strength_roll"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:weight=".2"**
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/roll"
    android:onClick="strength_roll_onclick"/>


</TableRow>
```

Something like. It'll surely work.

Comment: yay, it works! only I needed to change  android:weight_sum="1" to android:weightSum="1", and android:weight=".2" to android:layout_weight=".15". Now it looks like I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are using

TextView

ImageVeiw

ImageView

Button

put Button in between the images for center button.

Arrange them as you need

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. Should I put the button between the images? how will that change anything?

Comment: Yes just put <Button ... /> and put it anywhere you want.

Comment: LinearLayout just show the View where it is placed.  Changing the order will rearrange the Views.

Comment: Oh ! Every Tag within the layout file of android is called View. For example Button is a View, ImageView is View, LinearLayout is also a View, etc.